# No overload for method `destroyAfterCBEvent' takes `0' arguments

Tags: ios, c#-4.0, unity-game-engine, chartboost

Error: No overload for method `destroyAfterCBEvent' takes`0' arguments

What is the solution of above problem>???

```
Chartboost.CBManager.didFailToLoadInterstitialEvent += destroyAfterCBEvent();

void destroyAfterCBEvent (string location)
{
    Debug.LogError ("CB Event failed, noads button destroyed");
    Destroy (gameObject);
 }
```

These are the code which are used and generating the errors..

Answer (score 0):

You're *calling* `destroyAfterCBEvent`, when you actually want to use a method group conversion to create a delegate to subscribe to the event. You need to take the brackets off (which is what makes it a method call). You want:

```
Chartboost.CBManager.didFailToLoadInterstitialEvent += destroyAfterCBEvent;
```

That's equivalent to:

```
Chartboost.CBManager.didFailToLoadInterstitialEvent +=
    new Action<string>(destroyAfterCBEvent);
```

Or according to your comments:

```
Chartboost.CBManager.didFailToLoadInterstitialEvent +=
    new GUIClickEventReceiver(destroyAfterCBEvent);
```

(The latter surprises me, given the [Chartboost documentation](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/unity/delegates).)

As an aside, it would be a good idea to change your code to follow normal .NET naming conventions - events and methods should both be PascalCased. Events should usually have a delegate compatible with `EventHandler`, too. (I don't know anything about ChartBoost, so it's possible that some of these problems are nothing to do with you... but the method name is definitely something you can fix.)

Comment: SO WHAT SHOULD I do.. as i am new to c#, can you precisely suggest me what to do..@Jon Skeet ..I am programming it for Unity 3d project

Comment: @devean_purohit: I've shown you exactly what you should do to fix the problem - look at the line of code I've provided.

Comment: it is generating a new error on adding your code
The type `GUIClickEventReceiver' does not contain a constructor that takes `1' arguments
 here the GUIClickEventReceiver is the WhateverTheEventTypeIs...

Comment: @devean_purohit: Well then you presumably need to change the signature of your method to match `GUIClickEventReceiver`. I have to say, if you're new to C# then starting off in iOS with Unity and what I assume is a third party library is not the best idea.

Comment: thanks a lot for suggestion.. it worked..and for second one as well.. :)

Comment: @devean_purohit: Yes, the first is only a shorthand for the second. I'm glad it works now. I'm surprised that `GUIClickEventReceiver` is the type, given the documentation at https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/unity/delegates

Comment: @devean: I don't know what you mean. I'm saying that the documentation suggests that the event type is `Action<string>`, not `GUIClickEventReceiver`